# I cannot understand why this code gives a segmentation fault. Please, can anyone tell me where have I allocated a memory which cannot be used

Tags: c++

```
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
//There were problems in this code. the include wasnt showing up. So i just put them as comments.

using namespace std;

int main()   
{
    int n, a[n],count[100],temp;

    cin>>n;

    if(n<100||n>pow(10,6))
        return 0;

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        count[i]=0;
    }

    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cin>>a[j];

        if(a[j]<0||a[j]>=100)
            return 0;
    }

    for(int m=0;m<n;m++)
    {   
        temp=a[m];
        count[temp]++;
    }

    for(int s=0;s<100;s++)
    {
        cout<<count[s]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a[n]` is initialized as an array of size `n` but `n` is uninitialized

Comment: `int n, a[n],count[100],temp;` What is `n` here? Also `a[n]` is not legal in standard c++ anyways. Use std::vector instead.

Comment: short answer? int a[n] then you give value to n. imagine in between you try to reach a[5] and your n is not more than 5? memory allocation gives segmentation fault

Comment: As a side note: VLA's aren't standard c++ at all.

Comment: I find it odd that your first `if` essentially guarantees that no safe value of `n` can be provided by the user. Later loops imply that `n` should always be less than 100 (the number of elements in `count`) , but you abort if `n` less than 100 is provided.

Comment: Your code would be more efficient if you specified the numeric constant rather than `pow(10,6)`, almost the same amount of characters!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  actually the first if is for the no. Of elements in the array 'a', while the later if is used so that the values of the array 'a' don't exceed the range of 0-99.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions and help. I wasn't just able to look over this small thing. Was always thinking about the loops. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops!
Looks like you're trying to create a variable sized array (which doesn't exist... kinda) with an undefined variable (which can be anything the system wants it to be).
Use pointers instead, and let the user fill the variable before creating the array:

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
int* a = new int[n];
```

Or use the magic [C++ vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), since you're including them. They offer many more features than plain pointers like dynamic allocation and some newer methods of type-safety, along with multiple in-out methods like LIFO and FIFO:

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
std::vector<int> a(n);
```

Comment: Awwww, don't advise `new[]` please. What's wrong with `std::vector`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm working on it...

Comment: What's actually _"magic"_ about [C++ vectors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? There's all behavior stated well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your below statement is wrong:-

```
int n, a[n],count[100],temp;

cin>>n;
```

a fix size array declaration must need the size during compilation. In the above declaration `n` does not have a size during compilation. Hence compiler can not allocate memory from stack.

a